# Some of my learnable parameters are not being updated

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to build a Spiking Neural Network (SNN) from scratch using PyTorch. In the network, I have defined 7 learnable parameters as such:

```
class SNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,window_length,beta,dims):
        super(SNN,self).__init__()
        self.window_length=window_length
        self.beta=beta
        self.input_size=dims[0]
        self.hidden_size=dims[1]
        self.output_size=dims[2]
        
        self.a=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1,requires_grad=True))
        self.W0=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.input_size,requires_grad=True))
        self.W1=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True))
        self.W2=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.output_size,requires_grad=True))
        self.th0=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.input_size,requires_grad=True))
        self.th1=nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True))
        self.th2=nn.Parameter(3*torch.ones(self.output_size,requires_grad=True))

    def Layer(self,x):
        #I have three of such methods (for my three layers)
        n_samples=x.shape[0]
        window_length=self.window_length
        layer_size=self.hidden_size
        
        mems_sur_layer_output=torch.zeros(n_samples,layer_size,window_length)
        sout_sur_layer_output=torch.zeros(n_samples,layer_size,window_length)
        
        for i in range(layer_size):            
            sout_sur=torch.zeros(n_samples,window_length)
            mems_sur=torch.zeros(n_samples,window_length)
            mem=torch.zeros(n_samples)
            mem_sur=torch.zeros(n_samples)
            
            for time_step in range(window_length):
                mems_sur[:,time_step]=(self.beta*mem_sur+self.W0[i]*torch.sum(x[:,:,time_step],dim=[1]))
                #W0 is replaced with W1 and W2 in the two other layers
                
                x1=mems[:,time_step]-self.th0[i]
                #th0 is replaced with th1 and th2 in the two other layers
                s_sur=torch.sigmoid(x1)
                sout_sur[:,time_step]=s_sur

                mem_sur=mems_sur[:,time_step]*(1-s_sur)
        
            mems_sur_layer_output[:,i,:]=mems_sur
            sout_sur_layer_output[:,i,:]=sout_sur   

        return sout_sur_layer_output

    def Rate_Decode(self,x):
        return x/self.a

    def forward(self,x):
        output=self.Layer(x)
        #Layer() is called 3 times with the variable 'output' being the output of each call and the input of the next.
        return self.Rate_Decode(output)
```

When the model finishes training, only parameters `a` and `th2` are being updated.

I am building a simple network that adds two numbers together with a simple architecture (2x10x1). Any possible reasons on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is this code you wrote? It appears that not all seven paramters are being utilized in your loop. In your backprogation. only `sout_sur_layer_output` seems to be trains in your model. Perhaps you could debug step by step to monitor which paramters are actually being used.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This is a short version of the code where I am showing one function instead of my original 3. I have placed comments throughout the code where the function calls are repeated and where the additional parameters are being utilized.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).